# How to set a function along with its arguments as a callback?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code snippet:

```
$scope.delete=function(){
     foo('x',3);
};
```

Is there any cleaner way to write this? I mean when the callback function consist of one line with call another function? (clearly, I can not write it as `$scope.delete=foo('x',3)`)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

For example:

```
$scope.delete = foo.bind(null, 'x', 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind` as follows:

```
$scope.delete=foo.bind(this, 'x',3);
```

Where the first argument is the function context. That is, the value `this` will assume when the function is executed.

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.